# Why does Vref have this waveform?

Tags: pwm, flyback

According to the datasheet of the UC3843b

[image]

We have in the Vref output 5V DC, however when in my flyback circuit Vref has this waveform:

[image]

The secondary and auxiliary are not represented,

My circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS2aYb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Even when the FB is linked with Vref I have the same output.

Output of the auxiliary:
[image]
[image]

[PWM datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/uc3842b-d.pdf)

Comment: A couple of things - What are you powering this from? What voltage? I suspect the UVLO might be triggering the device shutdown. Also, the schematic seems incomplete - I'd expect to see a the FB pin feed in some way from the output, and perhaps also a snubber network around the MOSFET.

Comment: I supply 230 Vrms from an isolation transformer, I think you right, I found that:"When VCC is greater than 1 V and less than the UVLO threshold, a 5-kΩ resistor pulls VREF to ground. VREF
can be used as a logic output indicating power-system status because when VCC is lower than the UVLO
threshold, VREF is held low."

Comment: Please show how your auxiliary winding provides Vcc after initial startup.

Comment: Thanks, I put a transformer to represent the aux winding

Comment: Good. Please probe before R6. How does it look?

Comment: I hope it's clear with these new pictures "probe before R6", I don't understand why I still have 8Vrms  in Vcc whereas auxiliary  gives 1Vrms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are providing the supply voltage via 300 kilo-ohm resistor, so there not much current available for the chip to do useful work.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet explain the Vref pin response.
"When VCC is greater than 1 V and less than the UVLO threshold, a 5-kΩ resistor pulls VREF to ground. VREF can be used as a logic output indicating power-system status because when VCC is lower than the UVLO threshold, VREF is held low."[image]

My Vcc needs to exceed UVL0 threshold to have (typ 8.5V)
As we can see in the picture Vref is in yellow and Vcc in blue,
Vref = 5V when Vcc > Vurlo_threshold.